# Run a For Loop only if current row is odd

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, excel-formula

I am trying to run a loop to create some data as shown. I am trying to run this simple loop but would only like for it run for odd rows or even rows. I have a few ideas how to do this but don't know how to put it to code.

For example I am not sure if Excel VBA can handle something like: If Cell Value = S AND Row is Odd then...

Another thing I thought maybe a "Range" can be defined as only odd or even values but no luck. Is this possible?

```
Dim typecheck As Range

Set typecheck = Range("B1:B60") 'set the range itself to odd/even? or no range at all? just individually?

For Each cell In typecheck

    If cell.Value = "S" Then 'and odd row?

    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "_status"

    End If

Next
```

Expect result is, the loop will go through rows 1-60 and will produce a result only if the cell in the range has a value of S and the row is an odd row.

Comment: You're looking for the [`Mod` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa164528(v=office.10)).

Answer (score 1):

This will work:  `Mod` Function gives you the remainder. Use it as below.

```
Dim typecheck As Range

Set typecheck = Range("B1:B60") 

For Each cell In typecheck

    If cell.Value = "S" And Not cell.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then 'For Odd Row

    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "_status"

    End If

Next
```

It will pass the if condition on a odd row only. For Even Rows just remove `Not` from if condition.

We are checking the remainder after dividing the row number with 2, if `0` then it's an even row, if not then it's a odd row.

Comment: Thanks ! Figured out another way as well:
If (cell.Row / 2#) = Int(cell.Row / 2#) And cell.Value = "S" Then

But yours is more tidy :)

Comment: Using Mod will be shorter & cleaner though.

Comment: Optimally, you should need two `If`s: first one would check the oddness, the second one would match a string.

Comment: @JohnyL ... Didn't quite understand what you meant here ? When we can do that in the same line, why put two if condition ?

Comment: Because `And` in VBA is *not* short-circuting in VBA (as opposed to [AndAlso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/andalso-operator) in VB.NET). This means that it doesn't matter if first condition is false - the second condition will be checked *anyway*. By separating these checks, you eliminate unnecessary checks.

Comment: Yes That's the Purpose of `And` to check for both conditions, and both conditions should be true to pass. Which is exactly what is required in this scenario. @JohnyL