# Change font format in even rows

Tags: excel, vba

How could I change the format of the values in a specific column in the even rows

This is column F for example

```
One
two
three
four
five
```

```
One    
*two*    'Size 15 in italic
three 
*four*   'Size 15 in italic
five
```

I know how to do that over the entire column

```
Sub SetCellFormat()

   With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F")
    .Font.FontStyle = "Italic"
    font.Size = 15

   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Use Conditional Formatting using the formula `=ISEVEN(ROW($F1)`

Comment: Though, conditional formatting can't change the font size. So, you may need to loop. Use `Step 2` maybe when looping.

Comment: @BigBen good point.  Then the OP will need to loop the range.

Comment: Found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554370/run-a-for-loop-only-if-current-row-is-odd